# SonarQube upgrade fails from v5.1 to v5.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to upgrade SonarQube v5.1 to v5.2 and it fails with below error:

```
ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v52.RemoveDuplicatedComponentKeys
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row:..................................................................

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@7f872fa8 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.

2015.11.05 09:08:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=6911ms
2015.11.05 09:08:32 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v52.RemoveDuplicatedComponentKeys
```

Comment: Any progress with this issue? I have the same problem with upgrade from 5.0 to 5.2.

Comment: I haven't tried to upgrade later. SonarQube released version 5.3 and looks like this issue is addressed in that upgrade. https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7137

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I've deleted the duplicated projects from the projects table and then restarted the migration process.

To get an idea what is going on, execute the following query on your database:

```
select p.kee, COUNT(p.kee) FROM projects p GROUP BY p.kee HAVING COUNT(p.kee) > 1;
```

If you this query returns any elements you have to remove duplicated ones (e.g. the oldest ones). In my case it was easy because I had no isseues in the issue table related to projects in question.

I you have to mimic the SonarQube 5.2 migration procedure step by step (deleting duplicated projects and updating issues for them) you can find a list of queries being executed during the migration step on [Github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/0ae5ddd039e29094eee818370fe34810d3a225f7/sonar-db/src/main/java/org/sonar/db/version/v52/RemoveDuplicatedComponentKeys.java).